# Erro StackOverflow

Tags: java

Olá, eu gostária de saber por que eu recebo o erro StackOverflow nesse código, mas se eu adicionar mais uma condição no método recursive, que é if(lista.contains(numb)) eu não recebo esse erro.

(Esse código seria para verificar quantos números existem em base 3 respeitando a condição de que de um dígito d1 para um digito d2 exista a relação |d2-d1|<=2)

```
public static int recursive(int base,int numb,ArrayList<Integer> lista){
    inst=inst+1;
    if(numb<0 || numb>base-1) return 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> newArray=new ArrayList<Integer>(lista.size()+1); 
    for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++)
        newArray.add(lista.get(i));
    newArray.add(numb);
    cont++;

    recursive(base,numb-2,newArray);
    recursive(base,numb-1,newArray);
    recursive(base,numb+1,newArray); 
    recursive(base,numb+2,newArray);
    return cont;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<Integer> test=new ArrayList(11);
    int base=3;

    for(int i=1;i<11;i++){
        recursive(base,i,test);
    }
    System.out.println("Numeros validos "+ cont);
    System.out.println("Numero de instruções:"+inst);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

A resposta é bem simples:

Se você *não verificar* se um dado número já existe na sua lista, o seu código vai permanecer executando recursivamente pra sempre. E como chamadas recursivas involvem a criação de mais um item na [pilha de chamadas](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilha_de_chamada), uma hora a memória no seu sistema acaba e dá o erro citado - que literalmente se traduz como "sobrecarga" (*overflow*) da "pilha" (*stack*).

Como dá pra perceber isso acontecendo? É só depurar o código (mesmo que mentalmente):

1. A primeira vez que `recursive` é chamada, o valor de `i` é 1 (porque é logo no início do laço em `main`), e assim o valor de `numb` também será 1.
2. Esse valor é maior do que 0 e menor do que 3, então ok, o processo continua.
3. Ignorando as demais chamadas (pra facilitar), eventualmente a execução chegará na chamada com `numb+1` (que resulta em 2).
4. Nessa próxima chamada de `recursive`, o valor de `numb` como 2 também passa pelas checagens simples (é maior do que 0 e menor do que 3), então o processo continua.
5. Ignorando as demais chamadas (novamente, pra facilitar), eventualmente a execução chegará na chamada com `numb-1` (que volta a ser 1).

Assim, deve ser possível perceber que essa forma de implementação tem tudo pra dar errado e ficar eternamente em execução (em *loop*), a não ser que você ignore chamadas para valores que já foram processados (que é justamente adicionar a condição que você menciona).

Comment: Entendi!! A definição de StackOverflow eu já conhecia, mas não estava entendendo o porquê disso estar acontecendo. Agora estou tentando imaginar uma maneira de acabar com o loop, o numero pode conter digitos repetidos, mas o ArrayList não pode ser maior que a base, tentei adicionar if(lista.size()>base) return 0; mas não funcionou =/