# Stackoverflow em quick sort

Tags: java, quicksort

Estou tendo um problema aqui neste coódigo. Essas sao funcoes para um array de objectos usando o algoritmo de quick sort, e estou tendo o erro de Stackoverflow, e nao consigo identificar a origem. Alguem me ajude a identificar a origem do erro?

```
 static Musica[] ordenarMusicosIdQuickSort(Musica[] musica){
        return ordenarMusicosIDQuickSort(musica, 0, musica.length);
    }

    static Musica[] ordenarMusicosIDQuickSort(Musica[] musica, int left, int right){
        if(left<right){
            int posicaoPivot = partition(musica, left, right-1);
            musica = ordenarMusicosIDQuickSort(musica, left, right);
            musica = ordenarMusicosIDQuickSort(musica, posicaoPivot + 1, right);
        }
        return musica;
    }

    static int partitionID(Musica[] musica, int left, int right){
        Musica pivot=musica[right];
        int startR=left-1;

        for(int endR=left; endR<right; endR++){
            if(musica[endR].id_interprete>pivot.id_interprete){
                startR++;
                Musica temp=musica[endR];
                musica[endR]=musica[startR];
                musica[startR]=temp;
            }

        }
        Musica temp=musica[right];
        musica[right]=musica[startR+1];
        musica[startR+1]=temp;

        return startR+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack overflow lembra recursão infinita. Sua condição recursiva pode estar com problemas

Comment: Sim, sua recursão tem um problema

Comment: Um problema de Stack overflow no Stack overflow! Está mesmo no sitio certo!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema está em uma recursão infinita. Vou por o código original e, depois, a correção:

```
static Musica[] ordenarMusicosIDQuickSort(Musica[] musica, int left, int right){
        if(left<right){
            int posicaoPivot = partition(musica, left, right-1);
            musica = ordenarMusicosIDQuickSort(musica, left, right);
            musica = ordenarMusicosIDQuickSort(musica, posicaoPivot + 1, right);
        }
        return musica;
    }
```

Correção:

```
static Musica[] ordenarMusicosIDQuickSort(Musica[] musica, int left, int right){
        if(left<right){
            int posicaoPivot = partition(musica, left, right-1);
            musica = ordenarMusicosIDQuickSort(musica, left, posicaoPivot);
            musica = ordenarMusicosIDQuickSort(musica, posicaoPivot + 1, right);
        }
        return musica;
}
```

Viu a diferença? Não? Pois bem, ela é sutil.

O quicksort é definido em duas partes:

1. quicksort, a parte recursiva
2. partition, em que particiona de acordo com um valor pivô

No caso, quicksort é definido assim em pseudo código:

```
quicksort(left, right):
    if left < right:
        posPivot = partition(left, right)
        quicksort(left, posPivot)
        quicksort(posPivot + 1, right)
```

Note que, depois de particionar, se chama quicksort de `left` até a posição do pivô e, então, se chama outro quicksort depois da posição do pivô até `right`.

No código original, a primeira chamada recursiva não estava de `left` até a posição do pivô, mas de `left` até `right`.

Veja [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/59144/64969) para maiores detalhes sobre o erro *stackoverflow*.

Comment: Muito obrigado. a diferença era sutil a diferença mesmo

Comment: @StelioSpallanzani vou melhorar minha resposta, tive de publicar ela ainda truncada. Fico feliz que você tenha visto a diferença