# Troca ponteiros lista encadeada - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista-encadeada

Criei uma função pra trocar os ponteiros de uma lista encadeada, a ideia é bem simples, troco eles e atualizo o próximo elemento pra ele não perder a referência, só que a função tá perdendo a referência, p.ex., testei uma lista l = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, e quero trocar o 2 e o 4 de posição, ele me retorna l = 1, 2, 5, 6, quando deveria ser l = 1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6. Não sei mais o que fazer, testei várias alternativas e nada, segue o código:

```
def troca_teste(L): 
        p = L.head
        aux = p
        while p:
            if p.element == 2:
                q = p.next
                while q:                  
                    if q.element == 4:          
                        #swap dos ponteiros          
                        aux = q
                        q = p
                        q.next = aux.next                        
                        aux.next = p.next
                        p = aux                        
                        p.next = aux.next                                     
                        break  
                    q = q.next                   
            p = p.next
```

Definição das classes:

```
class LinkList:

    class Node:

        def __init__ (self, element = None, next = None):
            self.element = element
            self.next = next

    def __init__ (self):
        self.head = None
        self.size = 0
```

Comment: Como você definiu a classe de lista? E como você definiu a classe de elemento da lista?

Comment: Você disse que quer trocar algumas coisas de posição, mas não definiu no texto da pergunta o que o 2 ou o 4 tem de especial, assim sendo fica complicado tentar dar uma resposta que realmente sane sua dúvida. Eu particularmente fiquei confuso com o código dado seu texto de pergunta

Comment: A ideia é trocar dois elementos de uma lista, adjacentes ou não, no caso, como estou apenas testando as trocas, usei uma lista l = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, minha ideia é trocar o dois e o quatro de posição

Comment: Então o resultado esperado seria `1,4,3,2,5,6`?

Comment: Sim, fiz alterações no texto pra melhor compreensão

Comment: Você deseja trocar sempre esses elementos ou os elementos da segunda e quarta posição? Por exemplo, se for troca da segunda e quarta posição, `troca_teste(l); troca_teste(l)` retornaria a lista para seu estado original

Comment: É qualquer posição, como escrevi adjacentes ou não, esse código que postei é apenas um esboço, minha ideia pra esse código é utilizar ele pra usar em algoritmos de ordenação

Comment: Ok, você deseja fazer a operação `swap`. O ideal seria passar a lista e os dois índices. Vou tentar elaborar uma resposta

Answer (score 1):

Você deseja fazer uma operação de `swap`. O `swap` é uma operação que, dado um conjunto indexável e dois índices, troca de posição os elementos demorados por esses índices.

## Preliminares

Chamemos a lista indexável de `l`. Para o seu caso, `l` é uma instância de `LinkList`.

Devido à definição de `LinkList`, `l` não *está* indexado. Para fazer acessos indexados, a ideia é mais ou menos a seguinte:

```
def acesso_nodo(l, idx):
    # se o índice for além do que está armazenado, retorna nenhum nó
    if l.size <= idx < 0:
      return None
    atual = l.head
    while idx > 0:
        atual, idx = atua.next, idx - 1
    return atual
```

Note que essa função vai retornar o nó (instância de `Node`, não o elemento dentro do nó, e isso é proposital). Assim sendo, podemos dizer que, através de um índice, obtemos o nó associado. Agora podemos tratar `l` como um conjunto indexado, já que transformamos sua capacidade de ser indexado em fato (antes de `acesso_nodo`, instâncias de `LinkList` eram passíveis de sofrerem indexação, portanto indexáveis; depois dessa função, transformamos essa capacidade em realidade, daí agora podemos chamar `LinkList` de indexado).

## Fazendo a troca, mantendo estrutura

Como estamos fazendo uma operação de troca, a estrutura topológica da lista. Assim, ao obtermos os nós que apontam para os elementos de índice `k` e `j` (doravante denominados `nodo_k` e `nodo_j`), precisamos fazer apenas:

```
nodo_k.element, nodo_j.element = nodo_j.element, nodo_k.element
```

Então, fica aberto apenas identificar `nodo_j` e `nodo_k`. Sobre a função descrita na seção anterior, podemos fazer a seguinte função (relativamente não eficiente):

```
def swap_toplologico_1(l, j, k):
    nodo_j = acesso_nodo(l, j)
    nodo_k = acesso_nodo(l,k)
    if nodo_j != None and nodo_k != None:
        nodo_k.element, nodo_j.element = nodo_j.element, nodo_k.element
    return l
```

Note aqui que, para navegar até o maior índice, é necessário passar pelo menor índice. Em cima disso, podemos fazer uma otimização e diminuir o acesso a referência em pelo menos `o(min(j,k))`:

```
def swap_toplologico_2(l, j, k):
    (m, M) = (j, k) if j < k else (k, j)
    if M >= l.size or m == M or m < 0:
        return l
    atual = l.head
    while M >= 0:
        if m == 0:
            nodo_m = atual
        if M == 0:
            nodo_M = atual
        atual, m, M = atual.next, m - 1, M - 1
    nodo_m.element, nodo_M.element = nodo_M.element, nodo_m.element
    return l
```

Aqui, a ideia foi fazer a mesma iteração feita em `acesso_nodo` só que voltada para o maior elemento do índice passado, aproveitando quando se passa no menor índice para guardar seu valor. Note que, no laço, há condições para detectar quando se encontra o índice desejado e guardar nas variáveis `nodo_m` e `nodo_M`.

Para ter menos questões de ajustes condicionais, coloquei que `m` será o menor dos índices `j` e `k`, e `M` para ser o maior. Então, se `j` for o menor, então `nodo_j` é equivalente ao `nodo_m`; caso contrário, de `j` ser o maior elemento, então `nodo_M` que equivale a `nodo_j`. `nodo_k` fica com o outro nó em ambos os casos.

Também aproveitei e pus uma pequena tratativa para não precisar realizar nenhuma ação quando o índice passado para realizar a troca for o mesmo (ie, `j == k`), pois trivialmente fazer essa troca tem o mesmo efeito de não fazê-la.

## Troca topológica

A outra alternativa é fazendo a troca da estrutura propriamente dita. Os nós fisicamente mudam de estrutura. Como a lista é simplesmente encadeada, não é possível acessar o elemento anterior a partir do atual. Então, precisamos obter o elemento anterior aos dos índices passados para se fazer essa troca.

Assim como na troca mantendo a topologia, é possível escrever um código mais eficiente, mas aqui vou focar mais na lógica do que na performance. Fique a vontade para fazer a versão mais eficiente.

Para acessar os elementos anteriores a `j` e `k`, precisamos acessar os elementos `j-1` e `k-1`. Também é bom garantir que o maior elemento é um elemento válido. Outro ponto de atenção é que 0 é um caso especial, onde se faz necessário alterar `l.head`.

Para tratar de maneira mais simplificada quem é o maior e quem é o menor elemento, usarei a mesma lógica de `m,M` da função `swap_topologico_2`. Então verifico apenas se `m` é zero.

```
 def swap_trocando_estrutura(l, j, k):
     (m, M) = (j, k) if j < k else (k, j)
    if M >= l.size or m == M or m < 0:
        return l
    prev_M = acesso_nodo(l, M - 1)
    # tratar primeiro o caso de m ser 0
    if m == 0:
        next_head = l.head.next
        next_M = prev_M.next.next

        # trocando as referências dos elementos seguintes
        prev_M.next.next = next_head
        l.head.next = next_M

        # trocando as referências dos elementos desejados
        l.head, prev_M.next = prev_M.next, l.head
        return l
    else:
        prev_m = acesso_nodo(l, m - 1)

        next_m = prev_m.next.next
        next_M = prev_M.next.next

        # trocando as referências dos elementos seguintes
        prev_m.next.next = next_M
        prev_M.next.next = next_m

        # trocando as referências dos elementos desejados
        prev_m.next, prev_M.next = prev_M.next, prev_m.next
        return l
```

Note que foi necessário trocar os elementos de `nodo_m.next` e `nodo_M.next` de tal modo que fosse possível remover `nodo_m` e `nodo_M` de seus lugares atuais e manter a coerência da lista.

---

### Leitura recomendada

- [Inverter Lista Simples](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/217632/64969)
- [Como ordenar uma lista encadeada em ordem alfabética?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92516/64969)
- [Qual a melhor implementação do 'Algoritmo MergeSort'?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/235616/64969)
- [Stackoverflow em quick sort](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/218332/64969)
- [Na prática, qual a utilidade dos ponteiros em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/244828/64969)
- [Comentário distinguindo ponteiro e referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244828/na-pr%c3%a1tica-qual-a-utilidade-dos-ponteiros-em-c/244834#comment502630_244834)