# Ordenação por nome e matricula

Tags: c, classificação

Tenho essa Lista simplesmente encadeada e n sei como fazer pra ordena-la. Preciso ordenar por nome e matricula.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void BuscarMatricula();
void Inserir();
void Exibir();
void Remover();
int menu();
void OrdenaNome();


typedef struct registro 
{
    char nome[50];
    int matricula;
    float nota;
    struct registro *prox;
}Registro;


int menu()
{
    int op;
    printf("\n\tLista Encadeada Simples-\n");
    printf("Informe a opção desejada\n");
    printf("1 - Inserir\n");
    printf("2 - Buscar pro Matricula\n");
    printf("3 - Remover\n");
    printf("4 - Ordenar por nome\n");
    printf("5 - Ordenar por Matricula\n");
    printf("6 - Exibir os elementos da Lista\n");
    printf("7 - Calcular média da turma\n");
    scanf("%d", &op);
    return op;
}



void Inserir(Registro *inicio)
{
    Registro *novo;
    novo=inicio;
    if(novo->prox==NULL) // Alocação comúm;
    { 
        novo->prox=(Registro *)malloc(sizeof(Registro));
        novo = novo->prox;
    printf("Informe o nome do aluno\n");
    scanf("%s",novo->nome);
    __fpurge(stdin);

    printf("Informe a Matricula do Aluno\n");
    scanf("%d", &novo->matricula);

    printf("Informe a nota do Aluno\n");
    scanf("%f", &novo->nota);
    novo->prox = NULL;

    }
    else // novo apontando para uma posição já alocada;
    {
        novo=novo->prox;
        Inserir(novo);
    }

}

void Exibir(Registro *inicio)
{
    Registro *Exibir;
    Exibir=inicio->prox;
    if(Exibir==NULL)
    {
        printf("\t-------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("\tRegistro Vazio\n");
        printf("\t-------------------------------------------------\n");
    }
    else{
    do{
        printf("\t Nome do Aluno: %s | Matricula :%d | Nota: %.2f \n", Exibir->nome,Exibir->matricula,Exibir->nota );
        printf("\t-------------------------------------------------\n");
        Exibir=Exibir->prox;
    }while(Exibir!=NULL);
    }
}

void BuscarMatricula(Registro *inicio)
{
    int Pesquisar_matricula;
    Registro *Buscar;
    Buscar=inicio->prox;
    if(Buscar==NULL)
        {
        printf("\t-------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("\tRegistro Vazio\n");
        printf("\t-------------------------------------------------\n");
    }
    else{
    printf("Informe a matricula do aluno\n");
    scanf("%d", &Pesquisar_matricula);
    do{
        if(Pesquisar_matricula==Buscar->matricula)
        {
            printf("\t Nome do Aluno: %s | Matricula :%d | Nota: %.2f \n", Buscar->nome,Buscar->matricula,Buscar->nota );
            break;
        }
        else
            Buscar=Buscar->prox;
        if(Buscar==NULL)
            printf("Matricula não encontrada\n");
    }while(Buscar!=NULL);
    }
}

void Remover(Registro *inicio)
{
    int Pesquisar_matricula;
    Registro *Remover;
    Registro *anterior;
    Remover=inicio->prox;
    anterior=inicio;
    if(Remover==NULL)
        {
        printf("\t-------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("\tRegistro Vazio\n");
        printf("\t-------------------------------------------------\n");
    }
    else{
    printf("Informe a matricula do aluno\n");
    scanf("%d", &Pesquisar_matricula);
    do{
        if(Pesquisar_matricula==Remover->matricula)
        {
            printf("\t Aluno removido: %s | Matricula :%d | Nota: %.2f \n", Remover->nome,Remover->matricula,Remover->nota );
            anterior->prox=Remover->prox;
            free(Remover);
            break;
        }
        else
            Remover=Remover->prox;
            anterior=anterior->prox;
        if(Remover==NULL)
            printf("Matricula não encontrada\n");
    }while(Remover!=NULL);
    }
}

void OrdenaMatricula(Registro *inicio)
{
    int ss;
    Registro *Ordenar;
    Ordenar=inicio->prox;
    Registro *aux;



    while(Ordenar!=NULL)
    {
        aux=Ordenar->prox;
        while(aux!=NULL)
        {
            if(aux->matricula<Ordenar->matricula)
            {   
                ss=Ordenar->matricula;
                Ordenar->matricula=aux->matricula;
                aux->matricula=ss;
            }
        }   
        Ordenar=Ordenar->prox;
        aux=aux->prox;
    }

}





int main()
{ 
    Registro *inicio;
    inicio=(Registro *)malloc(sizeof(Registro));  
    inicio->prox=NULL;


    int op;
    int sair=0;
    int posvalida;
    while(!sair)
    {
        op=menu();
        switch(op)
        {
            case 1:{
                Inserir(inicio);
                break;

            }
            case 2:{
                BuscarMatricula(inicio);
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
                Remover(inicio);
                break;
            }
            case 5:{
                OrdenaMatricula(inicio);
                break;
            }
            case 6:{
                Exibir(inicio);
                break;
            }
            case 7:{
                sair=1;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A função `OrdenaMatricula` ficou bem perto de ficar a funcionar. Apenas tem o incremento do ponteiro `aux` no `while` errado e faltou utilizar o `nome` e a `nota`.

Pode modifica-la para:

```
void OrdenaMatricula(Registro *inicio) {
    int ss;
    char nometemp[50]; //variavel adicionada para o swap
    float notatemp; //variavel adicionada para o swap

    Registro *Ordenar;
    Ordenar=inicio->prox;
    Registro *aux;

    while(Ordenar!=NULL) {
        aux=Ordenar->prox;

        while(aux!=NULL) {
            if(aux->matricula<Ordenar->matricula) {
                //agora troca os 3 campos de dados de cada vez
                ss=Ordenar->matricula;
                strcpy(nometemp,Ordenar->nome);
                notatemp = Ordenar->nota;

                Ordenar->matricula=aux->matricula;
                strcpy(Ordenar->nome, aux->nome);
                Ordenar->nota = aux->nota;

                aux->matricula=ss;
                strcpy(aux->nome, nometemp);
                aux->nota = notatemp;
            }
            aux=aux->prox; //aux tem de navegar para o da frente aqui
        }
        //em vez de aqui, que era onde estava 
        Ordenar=Ordenar->prox;
    }   
}
```

[Veja o exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/Yuf5kR)

A ordenação por `nome` é exatamente igual mudando apenas o `if` do segundo `while`. Em vez de repetir toda a função para ordenar por nome pode tentar reaproveitar a lógica toda uma vez que é igual.

Existem várias formas de o fazer. Mostro uma que utiliza ponteiros para funções de forma a poder passar uma função de comparação dos registros. Para começar altera-se a função `OrdenaMatricula` para fazer receber uma função de comparação e fazer o `if` com base nessa função:

```
void Ordena(Registro *inicio, int *compara(Registro*,Registro*) ) {
    //--------------------------------^ função de comparação aqui
    ...

    while(Ordenar!=NULL) {
        aux=Ordenar->prox;
        while(aux!=NULL) {
            if(compara(aux, Ordenar) > 0) {
            //---^ comparação é feita agora chamando a função recebida com os 2 registros
                ...
            }
            aux=aux->prox;
        }
        Ordenar=Ordenar->prox;
    }
}
```

Repare que neste neste ultimo passo alterei o nome da função para `Ordena` uma vez que irá servir para as duas ordenações. Assumi também que a função de comparação retorna um inteiro com valor `>0` para maior, `<0` para menor e `0` para igual, ao estilo do `strcmp`.

A função de comparação para as matriculas ficaria assim:

```
int comparaMatriculas(Registro *r1, Registro *r2){
    return (r1->matricula - r2->matricula);
}
```

E no `main` a chamada ao `Ordena` tem agora de incluir esta ultima função:

```
case 5: {
    Ordena(inicio, comparaMatriculas /*<--aqui*/);
    break;
}
```

Para a comparação dos nomes precisa apenas de criar uma função que compare os nomes no qual se pode basear diretamente no `strcmp` de `<string.h>`

```
int comparaNomes(Registro *r1, Registro *r2){
    return strcmp(r1->nome, r2->nome);
}
```

E fazer a chamada correspondente no `main`:

```
case 4: {
    Ordena(inicio, comparaNomes );
    break;
}
```

---

**Notas adicionais**

Para tentar ficar enquadrado com o algoritmo e lógica da pergunta não alterei a forma como o ordenar em si estava a ser feito. Existem no entanto formas mais eficientes de fazer a ordenação, ainda que sejam consideravelmente mais complexas.

Pode:

- Trocar o algoritmo para um mais eficiente como o *Merge Sort*, que já lhe garante complexidade na ordem de O(n log n).
- Não fazer a troca dos elementos da lista por copia dos seus valores e sim  movendo apenas os ponteiros.

Comment: Falando em performance... Fiz [essa análise](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/235636/64969) para alguns métodos de ordenação no Java. Tempo médio para ordenar 30.000 elementos: melhor implementação de `BubbleSort` deu `1692.41 ms`; `MergeSort` deu `4.29 ms`

Comment: Isac, creio que seria melhor fazer apenas a troca topológica, sem alterar o conteúdo de cada nó, alterando apenas os ponteiros. Eu fiz algo semelhante aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/246301/64969

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Sim seria certamente melhor e mais eficiente como indiquei nas notas. Não o fiz não só para não trocar a lógica que o AP já tinha e também porque é consideravelmente mais complicado. Mais logo provavelmente irei complementar a resposta com essa solução também.